# Change the method to a static method and change the invocation of the method (Java)

Tags: java

Quick note: I'm still new to programming and static methods were not covered in my previous class. I have tried getting into contact with my professor, but it seems that she is a tad too busy to respond at the moment. The following is a non-graded assignment; I just want to know what I'm suppose to be doing here.

What I'm suppose to be doing:

> 1. Create a class named HelloPrinter that has one method that will do the following:
>      a. accept an int parameter as the number of times.
>      b. use that param as the sentinel value to use in the loop.
>      c. In the loop, use a switch statement to print out “Hello, Dr. Zhang” if the number is odd and “Hello, Class” if the number is even.
> 2. In the main method, instantiate an object of this class and use it to invoke the method.
> 3. Change the method to a static method and change the invocation of the method
> 4. In HelloPrinter, declare a private variable named counter1 and initialize it to zero, declare another int variable named counter2 and initialize it to zero
> 5. Add the word static for counter2.
> 6. Create a constructor for the HelloPrinter class that accepts no parameter. In the body of the constructor, increase both counter1 and counter2 by one.
> 7. Define another method in the class named getCounter1() that accepts no parameters but returns the value of counter1. Do the same for counter2
> 8. Define a toString() method for the HelloPrinter class. The method will return the value of counter1 and counter2 with labels.
> 9. Test all methods in the main program

What I have:

```
public class HelloPrinter{
      private int counter1 = 0;
      private static int counter2 = 0;

      public HelloPrinter(int n){
           for(int x=1;x<=n;x++){

                int i=x;
      //        System.out.println(x); <---testing only
                switch(i%2){
                case 0:
                      System.out.println("Hello Dr. Z");
                      break;
                case 1:
                      System.out.println("Hello Class");
                      break;
     }
  }
```

}

(I also already have the getters (getCounter1/getCounter2) and the toString, just don't want to flood.)
My question is how do I change the main method into a static method and change the invocation of the method? What needs to be done? And how would I go about doing it?
Again, this is not for a grade. It is suppose to be a refresher on Java. Unfortunately last semester our class was behind because she kept skipping parts and having to go back to them later (the college I go to needs more than one programming prof. if you ask me).

Any help would be grateful...
Thanks
-Iain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

main is always Static.

I think what you are asked to do is to have a non-static method in your class that does the printing. In order to call it from main you need to create an object from that class. Then add a static method to your class. To call the static method, you won't need to create an object from your class.

So:

1-

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     MyClass obj = new MyClass();
     obj.nonStaticMethod();
  }
```

2-

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     MyClass.staticMethod();
  }
```

Also, the main can be in the same class (MyClass) or you can create another class solely to contain main.

Comment: Ah damnit now I get it, and now I feel like an idiot for not seeing it before. Thank you Amir and Chris for your help on this.

Answer (score 0):

> is how do I change the main method into a static method and change the invocation of the method? What needs to be done?

The `main` method IS a static method:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // This is the entry point into any JAR file. This is the first line of use 
    // code ran by the JRE.
}
```

If you haven't got a `main` method your program won't run as an application. You should add a `main` method to the class, for example a class for testing, `Test`.

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       // Add in your testing code here.
    }

}
```

Comment: I think by "main method" he means the method outlined in point 1.

Answer (score 0):

"My question is how do I change the main method into a static method and change the invocation of the method? What needs to be done? And how would I go about doing it?"

First off, `main` is already supposed to be a static method; its signature is

```
public static void main(String args[])
```

(the name of the `String[]` doesn't matter, but the rest needs to be there.)

(If you weren't talking about `main` when you said "main method", you can ignore the three lines before this)

Second, it looks like you have 4,5,7, and 8 done. To tackle 1,2 and 3, you need to create a completely different method (like how `getCounter1()`, `getCounter2()` and `toString()` should be different methods of their own), and do what the instructions say.

For 6, the code you give us has a constructor taking one argument (`public HelloPrinter(int x)`) doing what the method from 1, 2, and 3 ought to have been doing. Like it says, you need a constructor taking no arguments (i.e. `public HelloPrinter() { ...`).

After all that you should call all of these methods from `main` itself (as 9 asks).